# TS Declaration for passing StyleSheet parameters

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I'm trying to find a way to make TypeScript accept passing variables to StyleSheet

Exemple:

```
<View style={[styles.foo(isVisible), styles.bar]} />

...

export default StyleSheet.create({
  foo: (isVisible: boolean) => ({
    opacity: isVisible ? 1 : 0
  })
  bar: {
    // something
  }
})
```

I tried to redeclare StyleSheet.create with the code below but I can't find a solution. Any idea ?

```
import 'react-native'

declare module 'react-native' {
  namespace StyleSheet {
    type Style = ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle
    type NamedStyles<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Style }

    export function create<T, S extends NamedStyles<S> | NamedStyles<any>>(
      styles: T | NamedStyles<S>,
    ): T & S
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just turn your `StyleSheet` constant into a function and pass optional props to it with explicit typing as follows.

```js
type StyleSheetProps = {
  isVisible?: boolean
}

const styles = (props?: StyleSheetProps) =>
  StyleSheet.create({
    opacityStyle: props?.isVisible ? 1 : 0
  })
```

And then use it as follows.

```js
<View style={[styles({isVisible: foo.isVisible()}).opacityStyle, styles().bar]} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really like this solution because if you have a lot of style in a file, your props will be too large and it's not very readable. Ideally, I would like to keep the writing format I shared